# Enable autocomplete when loaded by AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

trying to get my head around this problem:

I often load fragments of page via .load() function such as:

```
<div class="fragment_load">
    <form>
    <input id="typeaway" type="text" class="autocomplete"/>
    <label>Test Type</label>
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $("#typeaway").autocomplete({
        serviceUrl: "/restaway",
        minChars: 3,
        paramName: "query",
    });
    </script>
</div>
```

Now as you can imagine autocomplete is not working due to this.

I am unsure how to make it work going forwards for these small fragments that i load via AJAX.

Any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you could put the `autocomplete` initialisation code within the callback of the `load()` method, something like this:

```
$('#foo').load('bar.html', function() {
    $("#typeaway").autocomplete({
        serviceUrl: "/restaway",
        minChars: 3,
        paramName: "query",
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code:-

Just put it inside document.ready.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $("#typeaway").autocomplete({
        serviceUrl: "/restaway",
        minChars: 3,
        paramName: "query",
    });
 });
```